# Converting mtime To Days In Python

Tags: python, time, filemtime, pysftp

I have a file on a remote server, and I'm using pysftp to connect to the server. I'm trying to get how old the file is on the server and I can't seem to find a function to get the AGE in DAYS for the file using pysftp or Paramiko. (If I'm wrong, do tell please).

I'm using the mtime function to get the modified time for the file (assuming that was when it was last uploaded). How do I convert this mtime to DAYS? Dividing by 86,400 doesn't work as I'm guessing this is since Epoch time?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: what format is the mtime?

Comment: It's currently in seconds I believe. The following is the result: 1400536339

Comment: `days = (time.time() - 1400536339) // 86400`-- number of days since the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to days use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import timedelta
t= timedelta(seconds=1400536339)
print t.days
16209
```

using [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#module-time)

```
import time
t=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1400536339))
print t
2014-05-19 22:52:19
```

Comment: This is awesome but it's giving me a result of: 16209 .... Which is obviously insane lol.

Comment: That's the figure the server gave me... >_> Ahhh. Do you know of any function that can get me the upload time of the file on the server?

Comment: 1400536339 is epoch time. I will add an answer to convert it.

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to it!

Comment: does that look less insane?